# SQL Set/Declare Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I set my

```
declare @area as varchar(500)

set @area = '''Area1'',''Area2'''
```

I tried to put it in `WHERE` clause, but it doesn't detect `area`. I am guessing there is something wrong with `set @area =`?

This is what I'm trying to bring it in:

```
where area in (@area)
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: `area in (@area)` is the same as `area in ('''Area1''.''Area2''')`. So SQL Server is looking for an actual value in the table equal to the entire string: `'Area1','Area2'`. SQL Server doesn't know what an array is. If you want it to check multiple values you'll need to split that string up using a split function, or use dynamic SQL, or - preferably - by having them come in as separate values using a table-valued parameter. See http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings and http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql.

Comment: If you can explain where `'''Area1'',''Area2'''` comes from and what control you have over that, it will be much easier to help.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I will use ASP to execute execute this sql. ASP will will bring in area as "'Area1','Area2','Area3'''

Answer (score 1):

Since you've got a list of elements to compare against, use a [table variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to accumulate the comparison data, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @area as TABLE(Name VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @area(Name) VALUES ('Area1'), ('Area2');
```

You can then use this either:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyCol in (SELECT Name FROM @Area);
```

Or better, via a direct join (failed joins will be eliminated):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable INNER JOIN @Area
ON MyTable.MyCol = @Area.Name;
```

Comment: i cant use the table variable method, I'm trying to pass my asp area into sql

Comment: You still can - here are [some solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-a-sql-in-clause). You can also wrap the above into a PROC and then bind a Table Valued Parameter - ADO allows you to bind IEnumerables and DataTables to table parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a set rather then varchar variable:

```
where area in (select a from(values('Area1'),('Area2')) t(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
declare @area as varchar(500)

set @area = 'Area1,Area2'

SELECT * 
FROM TableName
where area in (
              SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Area
              FROM (SELECT  CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@area, ',', '</M><M>') 
                + '</M>' AS XML) AS String ) AS A
               CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
               )
```

Comment: Careful, if an area has characters like `&` this will break. Also we don't know the OP has control over the input format (you changed `''Area1'',''Area2''` to `Area1,Area2`).

Answer (score 0):

try use dynamic sql like-

```
declare @area as varchar(500)
set @area = 'Area1,Area2'
DECLARE @sql varchar(500)
set @sql='SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[tbl] AS t
WHERE area in ('+@area+')'
exec (@sql)
```

or

```
declare @area as varchar(500)
set @area = '''Area1'',''Area2'''
DECLARE @sql varchar(500)
set @sql='SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[tbl] AS t
WHERE area in ('+@area+')'
PRINT @sql
exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Result of your code

Query

```
declare @area as varchar(500)
set @area = '''Area1'',''Area2'''
```

Enter

```
print 'where area in (' + @area + ')'
```

Result

```
where area in ('Area1','Area2')
```